# How to 'continue' inside a each loop : underscore, node.js

Tags: node.js, loops, underscore.js

The code in node.js is simple enough.

```
_.each(users, function(u, index) {
  if (u.superUser === false) {
    //return false would break
    //continue?
  }
  //Some code
});
```

My question is how can I continue to next index without executing "Some code" if superUser is set to false?

PS: I know an else condition would solve the problem. Still curious to know the answer.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

```
_.each(users, function(u, index) {
  if (u.superUser === false) {
    return;
    //this does not break. _.each will always run
    //the iterator function for the entire array
    //return value from the iterator is ignored
  }
  //Some code
});
```

Side note that with lodash (not underscore) `_.forEach` if you DO want to end the "loop" early you can explicitly `return false` from the iteratee function and lodash will terminate the `forEach` loop early.

Comment: Why is this not applicable? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue

Comment: Because `_.each` and a regular `for () {}` loop are not the same thing.

Comment: @ConAntonakos When you use `for-each(collection, callback)` in JS there isn't any for loop inside `callback` hence `break/continue` do not apply.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of `continue` statement in for loop you can use `return` statement in `_.each()` in underscore.js it will skip the current iteration only.

Answer (score 0):

```
_.each(users, function(u, index) {
  if (u.superUser) {
    //Some code
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry. I should have put scenario in detail. I need to execute some code if super user is false and then continue. There will be another condition say, if (superUser != false && activated) for which I need to do something else and execute "Some code" and then there's else for which I need to execute "Some code". I just wanted to know if there's a way to do it without rewriting same code inside both else if and else. I do not want to create another function for this.

Comment: He was asking how to avoid that very poor practice of arrow-code.